# When to use or not use "a" after a verb? E.g. "voy a comer" and "quiero comer"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In English we think of the infinitive as being "to" + action. E.g. "to eat".
**There are cases where we use a verb followed directly by the infinitive.**
E.g. "quiero comer"

quiero = I want
comer = to eat
quiero comer = I want to eat

**However there are also many cases where we put "a" before the second verb.**
E.g. "voy a comer" or "empiezo a comer"
empiezo = I start
a = to
comer = to eat
empiezo a comer = I start (to) to eat

**Are there rules about when to include the "a" when to leave it out?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"A" precedes** the following verb most of all in ["perífrasis verbales"](http://www.materialesdelengua.org/LENGUA/morfologia/perifrasis/perifrasisverbales.htm). A lot of "perífrasis verbales" require a preposition (a, de...) or some other conjunction (like que, in *tengo que*). Some examples are:

- Empezar/comenzar/iniciar/principiar a [verbo]: *empiezo a comer*
- Ir a [verbo]: *voy a comer*
- Ponerse a [verbo]: *me pongo a comer*
- Volver a [verbo]: *vuelvo a comer*
- Llegar a [verbo]: *llego a comer*

However, some don't. Some "perífrasis verbales" that don't require an "a" are:

- Deber [verbo]: *debo comer*
- Soler [verbo]: *suelo comer*
- Poder [verbo]: *puedo comer*

There are also certain "perífrasis verbales" that take the gerund form of the verb. Almost none of them require the "a":

- Estar [verbo]: *estoy comiendo*
- Seguir [verbo]: *sigo comiendo*
- Continuar [verbo]: *continúo comiendo*
- Llevar [verbo]: *llevo comiendo [una hora]*

---

**"A" doesn't precede** the following verb most of all when the verb can be replaced by a pronoun (i.e., when it's a subject or a direct object):

- Quiero comer — "comer" is a DO, and so it can be replaced by "eso": *quiero eso*
- Me gusta comer — "comer" is the subject, and so it can be replaced by "eso": *me gusta eso*
- Merezco comer — "comer" is a DO, and so it can be replaced by "eso": *merezco eso*
- Conviene comer — "comer" is the subject, so it can be reaplaced by "eso": *conviene eso*

Look how the replacement by "eso" doesn't work with the "perífrasis verbales" cited above:

- Empiezo a eso (wrong).
- Voy a eso (wrong).
- Me pongo a eso (wrong).
- Vuelvo a eso (wrong).
- Llego a eso (wrong).
- Debo eso (wrong).
- Suelo eso (wrong).
- Puedo eso (wrong).
- Estoy eso (wrong).
- Sigo eso (wrong).
- Continúo eso (wrong).
- Llevo eso (wrong).

Although some instances with "eso/ello" instead of the verb in "perífrasis verbales" are idiomatic (such as "ponte a ello", "a eso vengo" or "ni a eso llego"), they are at least obscure from a grammatical point of view.

---

**Bottom line**: if you can susbstitute the verb by "eso", don't use "a". If you can't, use "a". If you do this, you will be right 3 out of 4 of the times. Three exceptions are "soler", "deber" and "poder", which don't require "a" even though you can't substitute the verb by "eso". Never use "a" before a gerund.

Comment: Could someone please explain what a gerund is? My understanding is that a gerund is a verb ending in -ing that you could replace with a noun (such as eso). For example (what you used above): estoy comiendo.

Comment: A gerund in Spanish ends with -ando/-endo. In English, gerunds can work as a noun, but in Spanish they can't. A gerund is only used in Spanish in continuous tenses (estoy comiendo) and as an adverb indicating the way something is done (ven corriendo). Unlike English, you could never replace a gerund with a noun or pronoun ("eso") in Spanish.