# ¿Por qué el cambio del tiempo verbal?

Tags: traducción, tiempos-verbales, inglés

Comentando esta pregunta [‘a’ after ayudar?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41010/a-after-ayudar), escribí:

*Al empezar a aprender a hablar español, solo aprendía los verbos. Quisiera que en ese momento alguien me hubiera aconsejado a aprenderlos más las proposiciones apropiadas, me habría ahorrado tener que volver a aprenderlos* (I wanted to say: ‘When I started to learn Spanish, I only learnt the verbs. I wish that back then someone had advised me to learn them with the appropriate proposition(s), it would have saved me having to go back and learn them again’).

@Danielillo me respondió: *I love when somebody corrects my written English. About your comment: –... Habría querido en ese momento que alguien me aconsejase aprender mejor las preposiciones adecuadas...*

Aunque le agradezco el comentario, me cuesta entender la gramática. ¿Por qué el cambio del tiempo verbal? ¿Debería haber escrito *quiero* en vez de *quisiera*, por ejemplo?

Comment: *Quisiera* (alone) is a wish, something I want to happen in the future. *Habría querido* is what I would have liked to happen at that time in the past. These verb tenses cannot be literally translated from English (as you do in the Q). The English language in terms of tenses is simpler and more immediate, the Latin languages are not.

Comment: Although it might appear so, I didn’t translate what I wanted to say literally, I chose the imperfect subjunctive because I thought it expressed the sense of impossibility. So you’re saying it’s grammatically incorrect to use *quisiera* to express a wish that is impossible? That the imperfect subjunctive form of querer can *only* be used when talking about the future (similar, perhaps, to *ojalá)?

Comment: In no case I have said it's incorrect, I only referred to how the sentence would be better constructed. Anyway, *I do say* there is something wrong with the original sentence as it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modos Verbales**

Como ocurre en todos los idiomas, la forma de interpretar la lengua depende mucho de quien y como la utilice, pues cada individuo intentará expresar sus ideas adoptando un lenguaje que dependerá, entre otros variados factores, de su experiencia, cultura, gusto, estilo personal... Por tanto, su uso y aprendizaje, aunque sea la lengua propia, debe ser continuo y diario, hallándose en su ejercicio habitual y mejora, una parte importante de nuestro cultivo personal, una de las razones por las que muchas personas venimos aquí.

Dicho esto;

"*Al empezar a aprender a hablar español, solo aprendía los verbos. Quisiera que en ese momento alguien me hubiera aconsejado a aprenderlos más las proposiciones apropiadas, me habría ahorrado tener que volver a aprenderlos* "

La frase que nos ocupa, si bien hay personas que prefieren construirla con el modo indicativo, personalmente la hubiera abordado a través del uso del modo "Subjuntivo", concretamente con el **pluscuamperfecto "Hubiera o Hubiese querido"** ya que en general el "subjuntivo"  expresa probabilidad, irrealidad o situaciones irreales, situaciones deseadas, conjeturas, aspectos inciertos,  hipotéticos, posibles acciones realizables... mientras que el indicativo en términos generales expresa realidad, hechos e información.

Mi forma de construirla con el **pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo**;

"***Hubiera querido** en ese momento que alguien me **hubiera enseñado** a utilizar los verbos con las preposiciones adecuadas, ya que eso me **hubiera ahorrado** tener que volver a estudiarlos*".

Seguramente que cada una de las personas a las que se le preguntase por esta cuestión respondería y se expresaría de manera distinta, pues en cada detalle del lenguaje, ya que en el fondo se pretende poner de relieve una misma idea, dependería de la elección y variación de las palabras, su posición, utilización del tiempo y modo verbal, etc. repercutiendo en los distintos sentidos gramaticales y en su valor dispar.

**Otros ejemplos combinados**;

- *Ojalá **hubiese aprendido** a utilizar los verbos con las preposiciones adecuadas*...
- *Ojalá alguien me **hubiera enseñado** a utilizar adecuadamente las preposiciones con los verbos, **me habría ahorrado** mucho tiempo*...
- *Si **hubiera investigado** a fondo toda esta gramática cuando estudiaba, **no habría tenido** tantos problemas en utilizarla después*...

**P.D**. Espero que entre todos podamos ayudarte a mejorar "**Traveller**".

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por una respuesta tan detallada

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti !